# Group by gives wrong title

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got this database structure:

```
 id | parent_id |    name    | num_begin | num_changes 
====|===========|============|===========|=============
 1  |     1     | 0001-0001  |    10     |      0      
 2  |     2     | 0001-0002  |    15     |      2      
 3  |     3     | 0001-0003  |    20     |      0      
 4  |     3     | testgroup  |    5      |      1
```

The user can make groups and subgroups. The subgroup get's a `parent_id`. The `testgroup` in the above table is a subgroup of 3.

Now I want to select the current numbers (`num_begin - num_changes`). So I made this query:

```
SELECT 
   name,
   ( SUM( num_begin ) - SUM( num_changes ) ) AS num_now
FROM 
   groups
GROUP BY 
   parent_id
ORDER BY 
   id DESC
```

The result is:

```
    name    |  num_now
============|===========
 0001-0001  |    10    
 0001-0002  |    13   
 testgroup  |    24
```

But I would like to have the name of the original group. So instead of `testgroup` it should be `0001-0003`

Any thoughts?

Comment: if your parent_id is always smaller than the id of the record (when it is not the same) you could add `sort by id asc`

Comment: @JoSSte, doesn't per se have to be smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a join on parents:

```
select p.name, 
       sum(c.num_begin) - sum(c.num_changes) as num_now
from groups c
join groups p on c.parent_id = p.id
group by p.id, p.name
```

When joining on parent you are getting the following results:

```
---------------------c-------------------------- | ----------p-------------...
id  parent_id  name       num_begin  num_changes | id  parent_id  name
1   1          0001-0001  10         0           | 1   1          0001-0001
2   2          0001-0002  15         2           | 2   2          0001-0002
3   3          0001-0003  20         0           | 3   3          0001-0003
4   3          testgroup  5          1           | 3   3          0001-0003
```

No you are grouping by `p` and calculating `c`.

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you for that. But I don't quite understand how it works...  could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @LinkinTED, I have added some explanations.